# Cant open project?

Tags: java, android, string, performance, intellij-idea

I am moving from my windows to my mac, and I want to import my android studio projects. So, I copied and pasted them into androidstudioprojects folder, and in android studio, I selected `import project` and clicked on my project:

[image]

However, I got this gradle build error:

```
Error:Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.EOFException: End of input at line 186 column 4
:app:mergeDebugResources FAILED
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> /Users/ruchirb/AndroidStudioProjects/Emergency/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug/values-te-rIN/values-te-rIN.xml: Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.EOFException: End of input at line 186 column 4
```

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

What can I do? I have never dealt with this kind of error before.

Thanks,

Ruchir

Comment: I would do as suggest in the comment below, and also for some reason I have to sometimes use import instead of open existing project. So once you move the project folder try that as well.

Answer (score 1):

Wow...I feel so stupid. I just had to clean the project. Thanks

Comment: Fixed the issue for me too. Thanks.